# Flexviews - Problems starting consumer_safe.sh

Tags: mysql

I ran consumer_safe.sh using the command:

> ./consumer_safe.sh --ini=consumer.ini &

I get the output "Restarting FlexCDC!" continually. 
It doesn't look as though the server ever starts successfully even though I see the process running.

I created a table and run add_table.php, but I can see that the changelog table wasn't updated after I added and removed rows from the test table.

I checked flexcdc.err and the only contents is:
Max_allowed_packet: 536870912

Has anyone else encountered this or have any ideas?